# Expected table. got nil error?

Tags: lua

In the following code

```
for k, smoke in pairs(self.smokes) do
     smoke.time = smoke.time - dt
     if smoke.time <= 0 then
       table.remove( self.smokes, k )
     end
   end
```

It's telling me that self.smokes is a nil value, although later in the code I declare

```
function ent:Smoke()
  table.insert( self.smokes, {time = 3, x = self.x, y = self.y} )
end
```

Anyone know my error? Thanks guys!

Comment: `table.insert(self.smokes, ...)` does not make `self.smokes` a table...

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

Because the function ent:Smoke is run later in the code.
Place it up at the top and it will work.

Comment: Ironic name XD, however, I did try this. Later in the code I run another table, and it gives the same error down there, and it's running the same self.smoke pair

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want this:

```
function ent:Smoke()
  self.smokes = {time = 3, x = self.x, y = self.y}
end
```

And you would need to change the other code too:

```
if self.smokes then
  self.smokes.time = self.smokes.time - dt
  if self.smoke.time <= 0 then
    self.smokes = nil
  end
end
```

The function `table.insert()` is for inserting into array type tables.